# collection.Mutablemapping Error in pyrebase Import

Tags: python, firebase, pyrebase

I have installed pyrebase library and tried importing it Like

```
import pyrebase
```

It gives following Error and i dont know how to fix it!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fire.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyrebase
  File "env\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrebase import initialize_app
  File "env\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "env\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "env\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "env\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):

AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

Tried following some stack overflow advice but those wewe not specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because pyrebase uses a deprecated collections module. Fixing this issue is possible but it leads to a chain of issues, I would recommend you to used pyrebase4 instead.

Comment: Please consider providing some reference links, documentation to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the Installation time, you can check the version of the gcloud, whether it is compatible or not.
else use the [pyrebase4](https://pypi.org/project/Pyrebase4/).

`pip install pyrebase4`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).